# Offset between rig and some mesh objects

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

So I am learning blender through the tutorials and been going through the Mr. Squeegee one on https://cloud.blender.org. I have been playing with the rigs and somehow I made a mess and trying to figure out how to solve this. 
How I got there: After following the tutorial, everything looked good, besides the fact that they did not IK the foot properly in the tutorial as they did not use the copy for the foot and so the foot would get detached if I transformed the body object too much or made him jump.

After I got the whole rigging going how I wanted it, somehow I messed up while toggling between pose mode and edit mode. Now some of my mesh objects are getting offset by the rig. If some one can point me in the right direction on how do i go about fixing this and what did I do wrong here, I would really appreciate. See attached blender file.

Here is the file: [image]

Comment: I don't know how it happened but anyway, if you move the feet in Object mode and put them where they are supposed to be, it works

Comment: Also, things are simpler if your character is one unique object, but it would mean reparent it (with the Empty Groups option as it looks more like a robot than a organic character, then fix the parentage with Vertex Groups assignments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set the rig in the center, select one by one the objects in the wrong position and Alt P "clear parent". Then, when everything is in place, re parent again with the right bone.

[image]